# Is it possible to provide a query name with a pg-promise QueryFile?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

When using query objects in pg-promise I see how it is possible to provide a query name along with the query text and values.

Is the same possible when using a QueryFile?

I have dug into the pg-promise code but so far have not found anything that looks like this is supported.  If it is not possible can anybody please help me understand why? Or if it could be possible, if it would be a worthwhile thing to investigate supporting?

Comment: [It tells you so in documentation](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) for `text` type = `string` | `QueryFile`.